# Better way to select window from GNOME-3 expose?

Tags: gnome

I hate having to use the mouse to select the window to focus after spreading all the windows. I'd have thought logically the arrow keys would allow you to select the window to go back into but no.

Is there any way to set it in GNOME-3 so that I can select my focus window from the expose menu with the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [**windowNavigator** shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/10/windownavigator/). When you enter the overlay view and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you'll see some numbers appear over your windows; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+number will select a particular window.

Comment: Thanks, just about exactly what I was looking for. Not dissimilar to the mouseless browsing tab selection in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few nice keyboard shortcuts that very useful for Gnome. Most keybindings can be viewed under the User Menu -> System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts

but for your viewing pleasure = snippit:

[This page](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/CheatSheet) contains brief descriptions of many GNOME Shell features, such as keybindings, drag and drop capabilities, and special utilities.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be one that allows keyboard navigation of the window previews in the overlay though.